# How to solve $\int\frac{1}{a^2\cos^2(x) + b^2 \sin^2(x)} \mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: indefinite-integrals

$$\int\frac{1}{a^2\cos^2(x) + b^2 \sin^2(x)} \mathrm{d}x$$
I’ve tried to express $\sin$ through $\cos$ in the denominator and vice versa but it didn’t simplify the task.

Comment: It can be written as $\frac{1}{b^2} \int \frac{\sec^2(x)}{(a/b)^2 + \tan^2(x)} \mathrm{d}x$. Substitute $\tan x = t$ and you will obtain a standard integral.

Comment: Mathematica shows the result is $\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{b \tan (x)}{a}\right)}{a b}$. You can verify the derivation.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int\frac{dx}{a^2\cos^2(x) + b^2 \sin^2(x)}=
$$

Dividing numerator and denominator by $\cos^2x$

$$
\int\frac{dx}{a^2\cos^2(x) + b^2 \sin^2(x)}=\int\frac{dx}{\cos^2(x)(a^2 + b^2 \tan^2(x))}=
$$

$$
=\int\frac{\sec^2 x \,dx}{a^2 + b^2 \tan^2(x)}=
$$

Let
$\tan x=t \implies \sec^2 xdx=dt $. Then,
$$\int\frac{dt}{a^2t^2 + b^2 }=\frac{1}{b^2}\int \frac{dt}{\left(\frac{a^2t^2}{b^2}\right)+1}=\frac{1}{b^2}\int \frac{dt}{\left(\frac{at}{b}\right)^2+1}$$

$$= \frac1{b^2}\,\frac ba\,\arctan\left(\frac{at}{b}\right)+c= \frac1{ab} \,\arctan\left(\frac{a\tan x}{b}\right)+c$$

Comment: Isn’t it bt/a (not at/b) in arctan in the penultimate line?

Comment: @SofiaIbragimova No. Sorry. Why this doubt?